# Report Filter - Cannot Use Formula?

Tags: reporting, formula, formula-field, custom-report-type

I am trying to customize an existing `Report` to filter based on a formula field. It was created with a `Custom Report Type` of `My Object with Child with Grand-Child`. Now we want to filter it based on a custom field which we can match against `$User.Username` to determine if it should be displayed (when it matches). We can write this formula at any of the three levels, but it is not showing up in the available fields to filter on. Is it not possible based on this report type?

I've tried `Checkbox`, `Number`, and `Text` as the formula type, on all three objects. None of them are allowing me to filter, despite the fact that some of the pre-existing formulae seem filterable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you add a new field to the object(s) used on a custom Report Type you have to go to this Report Type record and drag this new field to the layout (click on Edit Layout button first)
The funny thing is that I was doing this just a minute ago in my org :)

Comment: Phew, man I thought I was going crazy. WOOT!

Comment: And it's not Friday yet ))

Comment: Awesome!! It saves my day.