# Reports - Field not showing up on report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I am trying to create a custom report but a field on my contact object is not showing when I'm building that report even though I added that field to the page layout of the report.

On my contact object, the field is a formula field that is referencing a field on the account object. The formula is `Account.NO__c`.

I also added that field as a look-up and that worked no problem. It's just that the formula field is not showing up...

I tried looking at this solution: [reporting - Report Filter - Cannot Use Formula?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128584/report-filter-cannot-use-formula) but to no avail.

What could be happening here?

Comment: By Page layout of the report you mean the report type. Right? Can you also check the access for the field

Comment: FLS is given to that field?

Comment: @manjit_singh Yeah, I mean the page layout of the report type. Which field level access should I look at?

Comment: Go to the object and open the field which is not showing up. Make sure that is is visible to you profile.

Comment: Yup. That was the issue, it was not visible on my profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is that the field level security needs to be set correctly for your profile.

Comment: Isn't that part of comment?

Comment: Should I leave it in the comments? I don't want someone to scroll through the comments to find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**What worked for me:** Added newly created fields to the Report Type

The fields had been added to the object after the report type was created, so I had to add the fields to the report type.

**How I added the fields to the Report Type:** Salesforce > Setup > Home tab > quick search for and choose 'Report Types' > Click on the report type name > choose 'Edit Layout' Under 'Fields Available for Reports' > follow the instructions on that page to add the fields